# JBOSS 5 SQL Server nested Exception

Tags: sql-server-2008, jboss

this is my situation. I have an application running on 2 servers 24/7 in my client side:

Application server: TomCat + JBOSS 5
Database server: SQL Server 2008 R2

lately I encounter an error whereby every Thursday morning 6am my JBOSS hit this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1368)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1355)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.write(IOBuffer.java:1548)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.flush(IOBuffer.java:2368)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.writePacket(IOBuffer.java:2270)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.endMessage(IOBuffer.java:1877)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:4403)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:386)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:338)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:185)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:160)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:306)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:365)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor343.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:386)
at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:228)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:156)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:173)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:350)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invoke(TxInterceptorCMT.java:181)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.process(SecurityInterceptor.java:228)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:211)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.process(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:97)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.invoke(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138)
at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:650)
at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:1029)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor323.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
at org.jboss.invocation.unified.server.UnifiedInvoker.invoke(UnifiedInvoker.java:232)
at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:744)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:697)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:551)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:232)
```

And my app service give this error:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error; nested exception is: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error; nested exception is: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

My client claimed that there is no activity being done on DB nor Apps server on Thursday 6am, hence i had no idea what trigger this error..it happens only every Thursday 6am. Any help would me much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What's the network topology?  Is there a firewall between the front end and the database server?  If so, it could be the firewall recycling connections.